# Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string -laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5

My code was working fine before tested it with many ways no errors were there but suddenly it started giving this error.

```
Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string
```

Don't know why as I am not using any query while saving record here is my code.

```
$product = new Product();

    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->description = $request->description;
    $product->short_description = $request->short_description;
    $product->brand_id = $request->brand;
    $product->cat_id = $request->categories;
    $product->attr_id = $request->attributes;
    if ($request->is_active) {
        $product->is_active = 1;
    } else {
        $product->is_active = 0;
    }
    $product->save();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could mark the exact line causing that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the danger with accessing the request input data as direct properties on the request, instead of using the access methods (`input()`, `get()`, etc.).

The issue is that `attributes` is actually a publicly defined property on the request. So, when you access `$request->attributes`, you're not accessing the input value named `attributes`, you're accessing the real `attributes` property, which is a Symfony `ParameterBag`.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to update your code to:

```
$product->attr_id = $request->input('attributes');
```

Comment: sir thanks a lot your solution saved my day. Thank you so much I didn't noticed this `attributes` thing.